# Jquery: How to add the attribute disabled="disabled" to an option of a select form?

Tags: jquery

I have a form `<select>` element. This select has `<options>` I need to use jquery to itinerate all `<options>` and add the attribute `disabled="disabled"` if the text (shown for the option) doesn't begin with '-'

Look the picture to see what I mean.

[picture link](http://content.screencast.com/users/chefnelone/folders/Snagit/media/3ef50377-79b7-4b9c-828c-bcc0c7d66ffe/2013-02-08_10-28-21.jpeg)

Comment: I just needed a code to start with and there are several methods to do it. Downvotes...why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("select").find("option").each(function(i,e) {

          var t=$(e).text();
          if (t.replace(/^\-/,'')==t) e.disabled=true;
           });
```

edit the 0 index is nicer in fact but then e.disabled is more browser compliant; & find is faster

so

```
    $("select").find("option").each(function(i,e) {

          var t=$(e).text()['0'];
          if (t!=='-') e.disabled=true;
           });
```

Comment: ya i was but i saw it before your comment :)

Comment: No, the downvote was for the completely and totally unnecessary use of `replace`. As of your edit, you've at least dealt with that. (Even so, this is *not* the "most optimized snippet".)

Comment: `$("select").find("option").` is most optimized (unless some parent are cached obviously); `e.disabled=true;` most optimized as well; where can you make it faster ? nb: agree on the use of replace

Answer (score 3):

Just check the character at zero `index` of text if it is `-` or not

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/atetoc/4/edit)**

```
$('#selID option').each(function(){ 
   if($(this).text()[0] != '-') 
         this.disabled=true;
});
```

Comment: FWIW, beware that IE7 and earlier don't support `[]` on strings. But then, we really shouldn't support IE7 and earlier anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("YourSELECT options").each(function(){
  if(!$(this).html().startsWith("-"))
  {
      $(this).attr("disabled","true");
  }
});

String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) 
{return (this.match("^"+str)==str)}
```